# Синхронизация времени двух пк в Linux с помощью linuxptp

Tags: linux, синхронизация, ptp

Есть два ПК, соединённые Ethernet без каких-либо коммутаторов. Оба имеют одинаковую архитектуру и сетевки i210. Возникла задача протестировать временные задержки при односторонней передаче с точностью до нс/мкс и с помощью временных отметок.
Чтобы синхронизировать сразу обратил внимание на PTPv2 и на пакет linuxptpd. Сделал следующее.
На мастере:

```
ptp4l -f /etc/ptp4l.conf -i eth0 -m
phc2sys -s CLOCK_REATIME -c eth0 -m -w
```

В файле: [eth0] serverOnly 1

На слейве:

```
ptp4l -i eth0 -m -S
phc2sys -s eth0 -c CLOCK_REALTIME -m -w
```

Вывод ptp4l на мастере:

```
selected /dev/ptp0 as PTP clock
...
port 1 (eth0): assuming the grand master role
```

Вывод phc2sys на мастере даёт мне строки, в которых значения скачут, но в небольших диапозонах:

```
CLOCK_REALTIME phc offset -80 s2  freq -500 delay 7000
```

На слейве вывод ptp4l:

```
...
port1 (eth0): new foreign master
selected best master clock 
port 1(eth0): listening to uncalibrated on RS_SLAVE
master offset -7959 s2 freq -5072 path delay -850
port 1(eth0): UNCALIBRATED to SLAVE on MASTER_CLOCK_SELECTED
master offset 8 s2 freq +2958 path delay -12
...
master offset -10 s2 freq +2966 path delay -12
```

Вывод phc2sys на слейве:

```
ioctl PTP_SYS_OFFSET_EXTENDED: inappropriate ioctl for device
CLOCK_REALTIME phc offset 240 s2 freq +4542 delay 6330
...
CLOCK_REALTIME phc offset -300 s2 freq +4067 delay 7031
```

Правильно ли я настроил данные утилиты? Можно ли считать, что у меня часы синхронизировованы? И что мне даёт значение частоты freq? помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: вообще вроде как ntpd обычно используют для синхронизации времени.

Comment: NTP-серверы могут синхронизировать часы в лучшем случае до миллисекунды насколько я знаю, мне бы хотелось иметь более точное средство

Comment: [checking-clocks-synchronization](https://tsn.readthedocs.io/timesync.html#checking-clocks-synchronization) в конце этого раздела есть ссылка на скачку `check_clocks.c`, который вроде как делает проверку _что все нормально_.

Comment: @user207200, говорит о верной синхронизации, если и на первом, и на втором ПК запускать, но почему такие значения частоты в phc2sys, спасибо, что отправили данную ссылку

Comment: Всё равно я до конца не понимаю, без всяких GPS, если два пк и один из них мастер, то правильно ли я выше их синхронизирую